# Tesla's 'Roadster' made its DEBUT 2 years ago(word usage)

Tags: word-usage

Let's say Tesla made the 'Roadster's first public appearance 2 years ago. Which is correct:

> Tesla's 'Roadster' made its **DEBUT** 2 years ago.

Or

> Tesla's 'Roadster' **DEBUTED** 2 years ago.

Which one of these is more natural-sounding or correct?

Comment: One is noun the other is a verb. Both are correct and sound equally natural to me.

Comment: Nice, phew, I thought I would never be able to correctly use it.

Comment: . . . and 33 minutes later I see a typo in my original comment. ;)

Comment: Oh another thing, you can see the word **'Roadster's** in the very first sentence right, should it be **'Roadster's'** or just leave it as it is coz' it's correct?

Comment: It's a generic term (a mass noun), so it's not being used in a countable sense. Leaving it as singular is fine.

Comment: Also acceptable: "Tesla debuted their Roadster 2 years ago."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of them works.

"made its debut" uses *debut* as a noun - to mean *the public releasing of something new in a celebratory manner* or something like that. "they're planning the debut" uses the word this way.

"it debuted" is using *debuted* as the past tense of the verb *debut* - "it's debuting later today" uses the word the same way.

"debuted" seems to be slightly more popular than "made its debut", at least according to Google Ngrams:

[image]